# C# application slows Down after 20-30 mins?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have c# application which reads data from serial port. I have put serial read handler in timer with interval 1 second , because data coming every 1 second
on timer I calling

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
ReceivedText(serialPort1.ReadExisting());
```

I also showing received data in richtextbox just to check it getting proper data or not.
 But after 15-20 mins application slows down wont even respond.

```
 private void ReceivedText(string text)
 {
        if (this.rtbReceived.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback x = new SetTextCallback(ReceivedText);
            this.Invoke(x, new object[] { (text) });
        }
        else
        {
            this.rtbReceived.Text += text;
            serialdata = text;
            if (serialdata.Length > 0 &&
                serialdata.Length < 42 &&
                serialdata.Contains("#") ||
                serialdata.StartsWith(" #"))
            {
                serialdata.Trim();
                splitdata = serialdata.Split(' ');

                try
                {
                    txtBathTemp.Text = splitdata[3];
                    txtBaroPressure.Text = splitdata[4];

                    double stemp = double.Parse(splitdata[5]);

                    txtSampleTemp.Text = (Math.Round(stemp, 2)).ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception EX)
                { 
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing obvious in the posted code. Are you appending data to a UI control somewhere? Or are you accidentally subscribing repeatedly to the same event without ever unsubscribing?

Comment: no not appending to any Ui control. accidentally subscribing repeatedly to the same event without ever unsubscribing how can i check that??

Comment: how big does your text grow? when doing concatenation of += to text, it generate a new copy of the string, when doing so many times it is a performance killer, I suggest using StringBuilder that is more efficient when talking about a large number of concatenations.

Comment: Do you know the reason behind application slowing down? I mean - do you observe high CPU usage, high memory usage by application process? It seems like the issue is a little bigger than the receiving method. Share some code on how you append the data to text box, subscribe to events etc.

Comment: when it just receiving serial data memory usage was around 13-18 K in task manager .the application has crystal report too.. when i load crystal report memory goes to from 14k to 30-40 K in task manager.. and after closing crystal report memory still remains 40 K and above. after that gui slowing down. but i disposed crystal report after on closing.

Comment: @Bhushan You would need to check all your event subscriptions (`+=`) and ensure that they are either not being called repeatedly, or are being unsubscribed (`-=`) at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a chance that `this.rtbReceived.Text` grows up after some time. Even if it doesn't use huge amount of memory, constantly manipulating `String` is not efficent. Have you considered using `StringBuilder` instead?

Comment: i removed rich textbox .. but still after loading and closing crystal report memory seems goes to high then it stays there.